# SplashScreen establecer un tiempo mínimo de ejecución en Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Estoy modificando una splascreen, y quiero especificar una duración mínima que se muestre en pantalla, ahora lo tenia puesto con un `Runnable` que a x tiempo cargaba la `MainActivity`.

Lo que quiero es que si mientras se realiza el proceso de carga mediante un asyntask, si ha durado menos de lo especificado, que espere x tiempo antes de mostrar la `MainActivity`

**SplashScreen:** duración mínima 3 segundos

- Carga de datos: 2s
- esperar 1s
- lanzar MainActivity

Si la carga de datos es superior a 3 segundos, el punto esperar no es necesario

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Mi solución:**

- obtener milisegundos en onPreExecute `startTime`
- obtener milisegundos en onPostExecute `endTime`
- calcular tiempo transcurrido `elapsedTime = startTime - endTime`
- si se debe esperar `thread.sleep(espera)`

Dejo mi AsyncTask de prueba:

```
private class LoadTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Boolean> {
    private long startTime, endTime;

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {

        for (int i = 1; i <= 2; i++) {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            if (isCancelled()) break;
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long elapsedTime = endTime - startTime;
        if (elapsedTime < SPLASH_SCREEN_MIN_LENGTH) {
            long timeToGo = SPLASH_SCREEN_MIN_LENGTH - elapsedTime;
            try {
                Thread.sleep(timeToGo);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```